# If $a,b \in A$ and $A$ is an affine subspace, show that $A-a = A-b$

Tags: solution-verification, affine-geometry

I would like to get some help with my answer to this problem.

My answer:

> First, consider if $a=b$. This automatically gives us that the statement is true.
>
> Secondly, we consider when $a \neq b$.
>
> Pick any $x \in A$.
>
> Note that $x-b \in A-b$.
>
> Also, $x-a \in A-a$, but since $b \in A$, $b-a \in A-a$.
>
> Then, $x-a+a-b \in A-a$ by the fact that $A-a$ is a linear subspace.
>
> Thus, we get $x-b \in A-a$.
>
> This shows that $A-b \subseteq A-a$.
>
> And, we get $A-a \subseteq A-b$ with similar reasoning.
>
> Hence, $A-a=A-b$.

Although it looks correct to me, I am still doubtful with this answer because we normally say $A-b \subseteq A-a$ when we can say "if $x-b \in A-b$, then $x-b \in A-a$".

How should I reorder my answer to make it clearer? Or, if there's any error, how can it be fixed?

Comment: If you have shown that $L=A-a$ is a linear subspace then there is an easier answer. Since $b-a \in L$ then $a-b \in L$ and so $L=L+a-b = A-b$.

Comment: The case $a=b$ is unnecessary; the proof below it works the same regardless of whether $a$ and $b$ are equal or unequal.